# Two versions of jQuery running, can't get 'noConflict' to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a website for a customer and the site is using two versions of jQuery. One version is for the "Lava Lamp" navigation effect for the top site navigation links. The other version is for the "Smooth Div" image slider. I can only get one or the other to work, never both simultaneously even when I plugged in the 'noConflict' script. I have since removed the noConflict script and re-uploaded it to the server.

Here is the site: http://www.webexplosive.com/spokes

Comment: Is it feasible to switch to one version of jQuery? I believe that the noConflict releases control of the global `$` variable, but does not allow you to run multiple versions of jQuery.

Comment: I don't even see where you're using `noConflict` on that site.  Can you post your code please?

Comment: I said I had removed `noConflict` because it was either making one or the other work, or neither.

Comment: Okay, I just reuploaded the site with `noConflict` added back into it. Now neither the nav or the slider are working, so clearly i'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals You were actually correct. I deleted the older version and replaced it with the newer version, and voila, it works. Thanks everyone for your contributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare:

```
var jQuery_1_2_3 = $.noConflict(true);
```

It removes the `$` alias for jQuery. So you can't write :

```
$(function(){
   jQuery_1_2_3(selector).doSomething();
});
```

The initial `$` is undefined.

Needs to be:

```
jQuery_1_2_3(function(){
       jQuery_1_2_3(selector).doSomething();
});
```

OR ( if want to use `$` inside `document.ready` ):

```
/* pass "$" to ready handler argemnent*/
jQuery_1_2_3(function($){
       /* can use "$" inside read now*/
       $(selector).doSomething();
});
```

The API docs have good instructions and examples

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: Okay, I've tried what you said and it's still not right. Can you check my source to see if I've followed your instructions correctly?

Comment: only see one version of jQuery in source..and no errors being thrown